# The use of UncommonField<T> in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I just relfected over `WindowsBase.dll >> System.Windows.UncommonField<T>` and I wondered about the usage of this class...
E.g. it's used in the `Button`-class:

```
public class Button : ButtonBase
{    
    private static readonly UncommonField<KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler> FocusChangedEventHandlerField = new UncommonField<KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler>();
}
```

So what is the use of this "wrapper"?

Comment: This is internal class, so you can't use it.

Comment: I don't know what that is, but I would not worry too much about it. Since it's `internal`, and is not intended to be used by your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Short answer

It's used to lower memory usage.

#### Longer answer

Let's start with dependency properties. On each `DependencyObject`, a large number of dependency properties can be defined. Whether it's a "local" `DependencyProperty` such as `TextBox.Text` or an attached one like `Grid.Row`, most of them aren't ever set and only keep their default value. In order to avoid having each `DependencyObject` instance taking kilobytes of memory by storing a value for each defined dependency property, only values being different from the defaults are kept inside the instance.

Now meet the internal `UncommonField<T>` class. You can view it as a lightweight `DependencyProperty` without any metadata, coercion or property change notification. However, it uses the same mechanism as a real `DependencyProperty` regarding its value: it has to be different from the default to be stored inside the `DependencyObject`. Since the `KeyboardFocusChanged` event is rarely used (explaining the *uncommon* adjective), it makes sense to save a little memory here.

But you're probably not Microsoft writing a framework having to account for thousands of `DependencyObject` instances and optimize for a few bytes. Simply replace a `static UncommonField<T> someField` by an instance `T someField`.